# KCFinder for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, file-manager

I have used KCFinder (http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/download) with PHP in some projects and integrated with CKEditor (http://ckeditor.com/) and I would like to do the same thing with ASP.NET (ideally with MVC).

Has anyone been able to implement KCFinder for ASP.NET (even partially) ?

Or is there a similar File Manager for ASP.NET which can be integrated into CKEditor? I've been searching for one, but didn't find something similar to KCFinder.

Thanks.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: I've rolled back your edit. The title was correct, because KCFinder is the free version of CKFinder.

Comment: KCFinder isn't "the free version" of CKFinder. It's a file manager developed by another person, it's free and it seems that only supports PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the official page at http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/

> Only PHP5 server-side scripting is supported. GD extension is required and safe mode should be off. To work with client-side HTTP cache, the PHP must be installed as Apache module.

So, no. If you want a .net version of it, you will need to either fork one yourself or convince the author to rewrite the backend system so that it supports multiple backend connectors.

Or if you are feeling hardcore, you could try [using PHP within ASP.net pages](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/12/10/using-classic-asp-php-and-webform-pages-in-asp-net-mvc-views.aspx) - but I find that dirty, gross, icky, eww and wtf.